# Update Order Id of a Braintree transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, braintree

I've built a Ruby on Rails API that process payments through Braintree. For an specific request, I need to edit the "Order ID" field on braintree but I haven't found how to do so. I'm able to load the transaction by doing a:

```
bt = Braintree::Transaction.find('transaction_id')
```

and then I can print the bt.order_id but I don't know how to update that field. For what is worth, at this point the transaction's status is 'Authorized'.

I hope I made myself clear and you can give me a hand on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried do far? I presume the regular methods for updating aren't working?

Comment: I've tried the regular methods and yes, they don't work because there are no set methods for order_id.

Comment: @fabianraf, did you find anything? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When your create a transaction add custom fields:

Docs:
[Custom fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#custom_fields)

Like that:

```
result = gateway.transaction.sale(
      amount: "10.00",
      payment_method_nonce: nonce_from_the_client,
      options: {
        submit_for_settlement: true
      },
      custom_fields: {
                order_id: "1221XXX"
      }
)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I need to update a transaction after it has been created.